# Restrict transformation to Header row or Row 1 Power Query

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I need to find and replace the headers of my Source Table in Power query
I am able to do this with [BulkReplace](https://www.howtoexcel.org/bulk-replace-values/)
But this searches the entire table, is there a way to restrict BulkReplace to only the headers, or if not then I can demote the headers and run BulkReplace on just Row 1 of the Source Table

Thank you

sumAppHeads (Find Replace Table)
[image]

In my Power Query, I have

`BulkReplaceStepHeaders = fBulkReplaceStep(#"Demoted Headers", sumAppHeaders, Table.ColumnNames(#"Demoted Headers")),`

```
let BulkReplace = (DataTable as table, FindReplaceTable as table, DataTableColumn as list) =>
    let
        //Convert the FindReplaceTable to a list using the Table.ToRows function
        //so we can reference the list with an index number
        FindReplaceList = Table.ToRows(FindReplaceTable),
        //Count number of rows in the FindReplaceTable to determine
        //how many iterations are needed
        Counter = Table.RowCount(FindReplaceTable),
        //Define a function to iterate over our list 
        //with the Table.ReplaceValue function
        BulkReplaceValues = (DataTableTemp, n) => 
        let 
            //Replace values using nth item in FindReplaceList
            ReplaceTable = Table.ReplaceValue(
                DataTableTemp,
                //replace null with empty string in nth item
                if FindReplaceList{n}{0} = null then "" else FindReplaceList{n}{0},
                if FindReplaceList{n}{1} = null then "" else FindReplaceList{n}{1},
                Replacer.ReplaceValue,
                DataTableColumn
                )
        in
            //if we are not at the end of the FindReplaceList
            //then iterate through Table.ReplaceValue again
            if n = Counter - 1 
                then ReplaceTable
                else @BulkReplaceValues(ReplaceTable, n + 1),
        //Evaluate the sub-function at the first row
        Output = BulkReplaceValues(DataTable, 0)   
    in
        Output
in
    BulkReplace
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
BulkReplaceStepHeaders = fBulkReplaceStep(Table.FirstN(#"Demoted Headers", 1),sumAppHeaders,Table.ColumnNames(#"Demoted Headers")) & Table.Skip(#"Demoted Headers", 1),
```

Comment: Thank you.  I though something like this was possible

Answer (score 2):

1. Demote the headers
2. Transpose the table
3. Replace the old column names that are now all in Column1
4. Transpose the table back
5. Promote the headers

Comment: Ok, so I can do this after transposing with `BulkReplaceStep = fBulkReplace(#"Changed Type", sumAppHeaders, {"Column1"}),` But have I gained anything by it? Transposing and Re-Transposing must be at least as resource heavy as Find Replace an the entire sheet?

Comment: I'm doing this with huge tables and never had any performance issues. I guess the table isn't actually rewritten but just the indices are interpreted differently.

Answer (score 1):

This grabs the column names, merges against the replace table to find new names, then does a rename to use the new names

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
 #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Table.FromList(Table.ColumnNames(Source)), {"Column1"}, ReplaceTable, {"Find"}, "Table2", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table2", {"Replace"}, {"Replace"}),
#"NewNames" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Table2", "Custom", each if [Replace]=null then [Column1] else [Replace])[Custom],
#"Rename"=Table.RenameColumns( Source, List.Zip( { Table.ColumnNames( Source ), #"NewNames" } ) )
in #"Rename"
```

[image]

Comment: Thak you. Nice, does not even use `fBulkReplaceStep` I will study it I can follow 80% of it

Comment: Not sure why you prefer an answer using a function, but ok, happy to help